# Jquery get elements by multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a form I want to get data from all the input elements and two of the labels based on IDs which have text in common (Mycode.Field1 , Mycode.Field2). I am able to get the all the input elements by doing the below

```
$("form :input").serializeArray();
```

How do I get the other two fields along with all the input data? I have tired the below without success.

```
$("[form :input][id^= 'Mycode']").serializeArray()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also provide your form html to help us visualize your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use a comma, as that would select both the inputs and the elements that starts with the ID `Mycode` etc

```
$("form :input, [id^= 'Mycode']").serializeArray();
```